# Error trying to bind Syncfusion chart data in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, syncfusion

I am trying to work on a rough prototype for a Syncfusion chart. I can get the chart to bind to the data in the code behind, but when I try to draw the chart in Xaml and bind it that way I cannot get any data to draw. Here is my xaml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JunkChartTest"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms;assembly=Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms"
             x:Class="JunkChartTest.MainPage"
             Padding="5,50,5,5">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:SalesViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <chart:SfChart>

       <chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
           <chart:CategoryAxis/>
       </chart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

        <chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>
            <chart:NumericalAxis/>
        </chart:SfChart.SecondaryAxis>

        <chart:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding SalesData}"
                            XBindingPath="Year"
                            YBindingPath="Target"/>

        <chart:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding SalesData}"
                            XBindingPath="Year"
                            YBindingPath="Sale"/>

    </chart:SfChart>

</ContentPage>
```

And here is the data in the code behind...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Syncfusion.SfChart.XForms;
using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace JunkChartTest
    {
        [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
        public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

                          var viewModel = new SalesViewModel();
             }

            public class SaleInfo
            {
                public string Year { get; set; }
                public double Target { get; set; }
                public double Sale { get; set; }
            }

            public class SalesViewModel
            {

                public List<SaleInfo> SalesData { get; set; }

                public SalesViewModel()
                {
                    SalesData = new List<SaleInfo>();

                    SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2014", Target = 500, Sale = 342 });
                    SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2015", Target = 520, Sale = 393 });
                    SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2016", Target = 560, Sale = 431 });
                    SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2017", Target = 600, Sale = 520 });
                    SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2018", Target = 620, Sale = 578 });
                    SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2019", Target = 680, Sale = 900 });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have followed the code examples from SyncFusion but they don't seem to work. Any opinions are appreciated.

Comment: SalesViewModel is defined as a class inside of the MainPage class

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jason, completely missed that. I moved that class outside of the MainPage class and was able to bind my data in Xaml with the following Xaml code at the top of the page:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
   <local:SalesViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have analysed your code and let you know that you have created SalesViewModel class inside MainPage class. To resolve the issue, you have move the SalesViewModel class outside the MainPage. Please refer the below code.

```
Code snippet: 
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{ 
    public MainPage() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    } 
} 

public class SalesViewModel 
{ 

    public List<SaleInfo> SalesData { get; set; } 

    public SalesViewModel() 
    { 
        SalesData = new List<SaleInfo>(); 

        SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2014", Target = 500, Sale = 342 }); 
        SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2015", Target = 520, Sale = 393 }); 
        SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2016", Target = 560, Sale = 431 }); 
        SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2017", Target = 600, Sale = 520 }); 
        SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2018", Target = 620, Sale = 578 }); 
        SalesData.Add(new SaleInfo { Year = "2019", Target = 680, Sale = 900 }); 
    } 
} 

Sample - https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/245697/ze/SimpleSample-740513237.zip 

Regards,   
Muneesh Kumar G.
```